# How do i delimit each column by a comma and repeat this for the columns stored in a list?

Tags: python, pandas

Currently each column that I want to delimit stores address information (street,city,zipcode) and I want to separate each section in another column. Ex. Streets, city, zip codes will all have their own columns. However, I need to repeat this process for all columns stored in my list *address_columns*

**What the data looks like:**

address_columns = ['QUESTION_47', 'QUESTION_56', 'QUESTION_65', 'QUESTION_83', 'QUESTION_92']

(How each column looks like using Fake addresses)
QUESTION 47
64 Fordham St, Toms River, NJ 08753
7352 Poor House St. Hartford, CT 06106
8591 Peninsula Lane, Copperas Cove, TX 76522

Rough idea of how to implement my problem:\

**Step One.**

1. all strings before the first comma go in the first column
2. all strings before the second comma go in the second column
3. all strings before third comma go in the third column

   etc..

**Step Two.**

1. identify text after the last comma and put it in the last additional
   comma

**Step Three.**
Repeat for all columns in the list

Comment: can you assume that each row will have same number of columns?  for example in your sample 2nd row has just one comma

Comment: I wouldnt be able to assume that each row has the same number of columns

Comment: then delimiting by commas won't work.  since your data won't automatically land in 'street', 'address', 'city' boxes.  i.e. `123 My House, City, State` will expand to 3 columns, but `123 My House City, State` to two columns.  Which means that `City` from first, will end up in same column as `State` from second.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pandas.Series.str.split` method with the `expand=True` argument. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'q47': ['11 4 st,seattle,22222', '11 9st,chicago,23456']})

dfnew = df['q47'].str.split(',', expand=True).rename(columns={0:'street', 1:'city', 2:'zip'})
```

Answer (score 0):

lets say this is your data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'QUESTION_47': {0: '64 Fordham St, Toms River, NJ 08753', 
                                   1: '7352 Poor House St, Hartford, CT 06106',
                                    2: '8591 Peninsula Lane, Copperas Cove, TX 76522'},
                    'QUESTION_56': {0: '1234 Some House St, City, CT 11111',
                                    1: '234 Some Other St, City, AB 23456',
                                    2: '90 Yet Other St, City, AB 12345'}})
```

you can expand each column into 3, with suffix of question, and then stack them horizontally:

```
# holder dataframe
df_all = pd.DataFrame()

# loop over columns in dataframe
for c in df.columns:
    df_ = pd.DataFrame()
    ext= c[8:] #extract question number from column
    df_[['street'+ext, 'city'+ext, 'zipcode'+ext]] = df[c].str.split(',', expand=True)
    #concatenate new expansion to previously accumulated questyions
    df_all = pd.concat([df_all, df_], axis=1)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Could I avoid specifying the strings in each column and instead, pass the variable 'Column_47' to the for loop? I would hope that read_csv would have stored all the rows into columns QUESTION_47 and QUESTION_56